# Users unable to add attachment to case

Tags: case, permissions, attachment

My end users are not able to add an attachment to a Case they open. They can see the Attachment related List but don't have the Add Attachment button. It's only visible to System Admins. FYI: they have "Create, Add, Edit" permissions on Case, but not Delete.

Comment: What are your Sharing Settings for Cases?

Answer (score 1):

Because the are not the owner of the case they can not see the button